# Access to IIS running within wireless network

Tags: iis, web-server, website, wifi, ip-address

I'm making a web site/application and I want to be able to access the website from outside my LAN. I'm serving the site via IIS; When accessing the site from within my LAN everthing looks good, but when I try to reach it through my external IP address (found using http://www.whatismyip.com/) I'm reaching the Router's admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to login to your router and forward port 80 to your computer running IIS.

You may want to consider a shared host, there are several disadvantages to hosting at home, which are discussed a bit here:

- [What are some pitfalls of hosting a website from home?](https://serverfault.com/questions/4658/what-are-some-pitfalls-of-hosting-a-website-from-home)

I digress, this should help you out:

- http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostmyown.html

Also see:

- [Website hosting from home - IIS6](https://serverfault.com/questions/108232/website-hosting-from-home-iis6)
- [How hard is it to host from home?](https://serverfault.com/questions/63515/how-hard-is-it-to-host-from-home)

Comment: Hello iainlbc and thank you for your response
It seams to be my last solution becuase I want